# Does a temporary object gets created by calling a function with a numeric literal?

Tags: c++, initialization

Suppose I've got something simple like:

```
void f(int a){...}
int main()
{
   f(3);
   return 0;
}
```

How does the initialization happen on a slightly lower abstraction level when we call f(3) ? Does a temporary object gets created with a value of 3 or does it just initialize by copy-initialization ?

Primarily the reason for asking this was when I encountered that in this code:

```
void f(int a){...}
void f(int&& a){...}
int main()
{
   f(3);
   return 0;
}
```

...I get an error saying it is ambiguous. Since I'm quite sure that calling the function f(int&& a) we get a creation of temporary object which gets a lifetime extension with a reference a, I would also say that calling the f(int a) also invoke the creation of a temporary. Otherwise, shouldn't compiler choose to call f(int a) as being more effective?

Also is there a book maybe which covers this topic elegantly ?

Comment: [overload_resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) is a complicated subject which try to have "intuitive" behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantically (forgetting about inlining, optimization and stuff) the first snippet does not require a temporary.

```
void f(int a){...}
```

When you call this function as in `f(3)`, an integer object is created using (pseudo) copy-constructor of `int` to be used as function argument. This becomes a local parameter to the function, and it's life-time ends when function returns.

Meanwhile, the second snippet

```
void f(int&& a){...}
```

requires calling code to create a temporary int variable (as you can't bind a reference of any kind to numeric literal). After that an rvalue reference is bound to created temporary.

And to your question of 'efficiency', compilers do not select function overloads based on efficiency. They do this based on a certain ranking of conversions, and in your case, copy and a reference binding have the same rank. You can read more about overload resolution here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: Finally the answer I was looking for. When someone advised me to find the answer myself using godbolt, I almost lost all the hope :D

Comment: @GRRohman imho thats not a good advice, as-if rule, undefined behavior, etc make it difficult to deduce the rules of the language only by inspecting compiler output

Comment: @idclev463035818 Most definitely agreed.

Comment: @SergeyA Would it still be correct if I'd say "..an integer object is created using ..." instead of " ..an integer argument is created using.." as in your answer ? It would be easier to understand, that's all.

Comment: @GRRohman i do not see significant difference here. An integer object is created, of course, which becomes the argument. I can add this wording if it makes it easier to read.

Comment: @SergeyA If you wouldn't mind, that would be helpful actually. I'm still kinda struggling with the correct use of appropriate words.

Comment: @GRRohman i made some changes, hopefully it is more clear now.